# How to stream videos on Flutter video_player?

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I'm trying to implement streaming video in my Flutter app using HLS. I'm currently using AWS MediaConvert to transcode my video from mp4 into HLS. I want to restrict the ability to view a video to particular users so I'm using CloudFront Signed URLs. However, when I pass the presigned URL into Flutter's video_player it does not work.

```
final videoURL = await repo.getVideoURL(video);
videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(videoURL);
```

The presigned URL is in the form

```
https://xyz.cloudfront.net/video.m3u8?Policy=xyz&Key-Pair-Id=xyz
```

Is there another recommended way of setting up streaming video in a Flutter application?

Comment: Try to use a https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_playout

Answer (score 0):

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85283) in `video_player` with signed url playback. There's no known workaround at present, but as an alternative, you can download the video to the device and play it locally using video_player in the meantime.